# remove element from dictionary in python

Tags: python

I am trying to remove the element that have minimum value in the dictionary to try to arrange the rest to the ascending order;

```
dict={}
for line in file:
    line = line.split()
    dict.update({line[0]:line[1]})

while dict.items():
    min = float(100)
    for x in dict:
        print(dict[x])
        g=float(dict[x])
        if (g<min):
            min=float(dict[x])
    print(min)

for name, avg in dict.items():
    if float(avg) == min:
        print(name)

fileout.write(name+ '\t' + str(avg) + '\n')
del dict[name]
print(dict)
```

Comment: Consider using another name for ```min``` variable, ```min``` is a reserved word in python and referst to the function ```min()``` to calculate the ```minimum```

Comment: btw Don't use variable names like `dict`. This is a built-in and this may cause problems in your code.

Comment: After the loop, `name` is key of the last item in the dict, not the one with the minimum value. You need another variable to hold that.

Comment: You found the minimum item in the dict - but all you did with it was print it; you didn't save that particular value of `name` for later use.

Comment: You don't need a loop to find the minimum value: `min_value = min(d.values())`

Comment: Where is your code that tries to arrange the rest in ascending order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to build a new dictionary from the previous one. By using `sorted`, `dict.items()` and passing `key` as `lambda i: i[1]` we can build a sorted dictionary. Finally we want to get all bar the first value and so we need to slice the result of `sorted`

```
d = {'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
new_d = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda i: i[1])[1:])
print(new_d)
# {'c': 2, 'a': 3}
```

If you have to mutate the first object then we can just clear and rebuild it with `dict.update`.

```
d = {'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
new_d = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda i: i[1])[1:]
d.clear()
d.update(new_d)
print(d)
# {'c': 2, 'a': 3}
```

Comment: Leaving a [mega thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value) on sorting dictionaries for OP's reference to along with this answer. Upvoted.

Comment: I should save the sorted dictionary in new file, so where is the element that is removed?

Comment: @HanofyAlnaemi You can get that by using `print(new_d[0])` in the second version.

Comment: it sorted for me by key, how can i make it by value?

Comment: @HanofyAlnaemi No it's not.

Comment: ok, it worked, but the first value or the minimum its not saved, how can I keep it in the dictionary?

Comment: @HanofyAlnaemi Remove the `[1:]` to keep the first value in the dictionary.